# Ubuntu Precise - Monitor Boot Activity

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My Ubuntu Precise server keeps crashing about 10 seconds after boot. I'm trying to debug it but I can't even view the log files because it'll crash before I have a chance to change directories or open the log file(s).

Is there a command that will allow me to monitor all activity of my server to see what's causing it to crash?

Comment: Please be more specific to "crashing". Do you get a kernel panic? Is a vital service daemon segfaulting? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is go into Recovery mode and check the logs over there.

To go into recovery mode, use like this.

Keep SHIFT key pressed when the computer starts. Once you get the menu, there will be a option for RECOVERY mode.

Boot into that. Once you are into the shell, go to the logs directory /var/log/ and check the logs.